# PHP Loop/Conditional Suggestion for Website Navigation?

Tags: php, oracle

Writing my first php application. I'm stuck on how to add either a loop or conditional statement...I'm adding my sites navigation from Oracle database queries...a primary and secondary navigation...I've noted in my code where I need an if or while statement to decide if a **ul** tag is written. I only want the **ul class = sub** tag written and subsequent **li** list when I have secondary navigation under the primary navigation. Any suggestion that would point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance...

`

```
        $t1_query = "SELECT * FROM PLUS_NAV_T1 ORDER BY POSITION ASC";
        $t1_parse = oci_parse($sm_conn, $t1_query);
        oci_execute ($t1_parse);
        /* Add query error catch*/

        while ($t1_row = oci_fetch_array($t1_parse, OCI_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"#\" title=\"\" class=\"exp\"><span>{$t1_row["T1_NAME"]}</span></a>";

                $t2_query = "SELECT * FROM PLUS_NAV_T2 WHERE T1_ID_FK = {$t1_row["ID_PK"]} ORDER BY POSITION ASC ";
                $t2_parse = oci_parse($sm_conn, $t2_query);
                oci_execute ($t2_parse);
                /* Add query error catch*/

                /*Need a conditional here so ul tag is only written when the primary nav has secondary nav*/
                    echo "<ul class=\"sub\">";
                    while ($t2_row = oci_fetch_array($t2_parse, OCI_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<li><a href=\"#\" title=\"\" style=\"color\">{$t2_row["T2_NAME"]}</a></li>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";

            echo "</li>";
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Oracle driver, but you probably want the [`oci_num_rows()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php) function. After you issue the second query, you should be able to call that function, and check if it returns a non-zero value:

```
if (oci_num_rows($t2_parse)) {
    // your code to output the UL
}
```

Actually, you should probably also verify that oci_execute() returns true, so maybe something like:

```
if (oci_execute($t2_parse) && oci_num_rows($t2_parse)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex. I looked into using oci_num_rows as you suggested, but I couldn't figure out exactly how to get it to work. However, on the php.net page for oci_num_rows, a user contributed a suggestion for counting the rows which I altered and worked. I ended up using oci_define_by_name($count_results, 'NUMBER_OF_ROWS', $number_of_rows); Thanks for the help.